# SQL 2008: Extract XML from nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I've read all of the other posts on this subject but none are working for me. This one is the closest [CONVERTING SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) TO XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946777/converting-sql-nvarcharmax-to-xml-and-getting-a-value-from-xml-string)

So, I've modified that code to try and fit my situation. I have a nvarchar(max) column that contains XML data as one big long string. It's not my database, so I can't change the datatype to XML. The next best thing is to create a query and cast it as XML. Here is my code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XML_Dummy') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #XML_Dummy

GO

CREATE TABLE #XML_Dummy
        (
            [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                                 NOT NULL ,
            [XMLValue] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
        );         
GO
INSERT  INTO #XML_Dummy
                ( 
                    [XMLValue]
                )
select top 10 xmlcol from MyTable

GO  

SELECT
        b.x.value('(/Proponix/Header/SubHeader/InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM
        #XML_Dummy a
        CROSS APPLY (
                                    SELECT
                                     CAST(CAST ([XMLValue] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML) x
                                ) b;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XML_Dummy') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #XML_Dummy;
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting all NULLS back. I want to return the InstrumentID. Here is an excerpt of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Proponix>
    <Header>
        Header stuff
    </Header>
    <SubHeader>
        <InstrumentID>BS6000000001</InstrumentID>
    </SubHeader>
    A lot more fields
```

What am I missing? This is my first time working with XML in SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to find the SubHeader as a child of Header but it is a sibling...

Try this:

EDIT: changed @x to simulate a table with a nvarchar-column containing different xml_msg values:

EDIT2: adapted according to calls the OP showed in chat

```
WITH ConvertedToXML AS 
( 
SELECT xml_msg AsVarchar 
,CAST(xml_msg AS XML) AS AsXml 
FROM myTable 
) 
SELECT ConvertedToXML.AsVarchar 
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml 
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(/Proponix/SubHeader/InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS InstrumentID 
FROM ConvertedToXML
```

--old Text

```
    declare @x table(xml_msg nvarchar(max));
insert into @x VALUES
('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Proponix>
    <Header>
        Header stuff
    </Header>
    <SubHeader>
        <InstrumentID>BS6000000001</InstrumentID>
    </SubHeader>
</Proponix>')
,('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Proponix>
    <Header>
        Header stuff
    </Header>
    <SubHeader>
        <InstrumentID>BS6000000002</InstrumentID>
    </SubHeader>
</Proponix>')
,('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Proponix>
    <Header>
        Header stuff
    </Header>
    <SubHeader>
        <InstrumentID>BS6000000003</InstrumentID>
    </SubHeader>
</Proponix>');

WITH ConvertedToXML AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10 CAST(xml_msg AS XML) AS AsXml FROM @x
)
SELECT
        ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(/Proponix/SubHeader/InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM ConvertedToXML
```

Comment: If I just copy and paste your code, it works. If I change it to declare @x nvarchar(max)='select top 10 xml_msg from mytable'; it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: You cannot set a variable to a result set. Try to change the CTE to `SELECT TOP 10 CAST(xml_msg AS XML) AS AsXml FROM mytable`  (instead of the `SELECT cast(@x as xml) AS AsXML`)

Comment: It is still returning all NULLS.

Comment: I just edited my answer to simulate your table. Please vote up and/or mark as accepted if helpfull, thx!

Comment: Once again, this works if I just copy and paste it but if I do the insert into the table variable with select, it returns null. Can you create a temp table with the xml contents with no cr/lf in it and show me how you can insert those results into the table variable? That is what matches my environment. Thanks for all of your help. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: @MattWilliamson, Did you try just to set the `FROM @x`to your actual table's name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89824/discussion-between-matt-williamson-and-shnugo).

Comment: Yes, I have. still all NULLs.

Comment: @MattWilliamson Answered in the chat, did not use this before as well. Let's test it :-)

Comment: @MattWilliamson, hi had something else to do first. I edited my answer once again because the chat seems to be not the best place for longer text. please read the remarks I gave there, Hope this solves your issue. And please vote up and mark as accepted if helpful, thx!

Answer (score 2):

SubHeader is not a child of Header in your example. Try:

```
b.x.value('(/Proponix/SubHeader/InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

Comment: It's still returning all NULLS after removing the Header tag.

Comment: It should work with the xml excerpt you posted. Can you post the full xml? Are there any differences between your pasted code and what you are actually doing?

Comment: The full XML is 283 lines long and contains sensitive data that I would have to scrub.

Comment: Try to isolate the issue to something that can be posted.